# Single Post Gallery Using Shortcode

Tags: posts, blog

So i made a blog and I would like to put all the images in a post in a gallery/slider.

I'm using the Enfold Child Theme so I looked up the gallery shortcode and made this function in the single.php(Single Post) where I get the image ids from a post and then I put them in the shortcode.

The problem is, it doesn't show any images.. I Tried using the shortcode in a single post where I hardcoded the ids in the shortcode, and that worked perfectly.

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong here or has a better solution? Thanks

`Single.php`:

```php
<?php
if (!function_exists('get_associated_media')) {

    function get_associated_media($post_id) {
        $attachmentIds = array();
        $media = get_children(array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'post_parent' => $post_id,
            'post_status' => 'inherit',
            'post_mime_type' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'),
            'numberposts' => -1
        ));

        foreach ($media as $file) {
            $attachmentIds[] = $file->ID;
        }
        $attachmentIds[] = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
        echo do_shortcode('[av_gallery ids="' . implode(",", $attachmentIds) . '" type="slideshow" style="big_thumb" preview_size="portfolio" crop_big_preview_thumbnail="avia-gallery-big-crop-thumb" thumb_size="portfolio" columns="5" imagelink="lightbox" lazyload="avia_lazyload" av_uid="av-jgesnq4m" custom_class="av-gallery-style-"]');
        return array_unique($attachmentIds);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: unrelated, but, your loop to get the IDs can be simplified to `$attachmentIds = wp_list_pluck( $media, 'ID' );`. You should also check the assumption that `$media` isn't empty, and I'd recommend not using `get_children` and instead using `get_posts` with `post_parent` set, it's more reliable and closer to how you're expecting `get_children` to work. It's also very likely that the solution to your problem is theme specific. I would also avoid defining functions in templates like this

Comment: Have you confirmed that hardcoding the IDs works? If  the ID's are correct but the shortcode still does not work, then you will need to get in touch with the plugin/theme authors that implemented the `[av_gallery]` shortcode