# How to get Images post ID (to use with Enfold gallery)

Tags: posts, blog

I made a blog with posts, and i would like to show the attached images in a post in a gallery in the single.php.

But I get this error when opening a post..
A critical error has occurred on this site.

Here i get all the images and their ids

functions.php:

```
function prefix_get_img_ids($atts) {
    global $post;
    $images = (array) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-listing-pictures', false); // cast to array in case there is only one item
    $ids = array();
    global $wpdb;
    foreach($images as $img) {
        $query = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE guid='$img'";
        $id = $wpdb->get_var($query);
        $ids[] = $id;
    }
    return implode(",",$ids);
}
add_shortcode("get-image-ids", "prefix_get_img_ids");
```

Here i use the shortcode with the shortcode in the 'ids' tag.

Single.php:

```
<?php 
    echo do_shortcode("[av_gallery ids="[get-image-ids]" style='big_thumb' preview_size='portfolio' crop_big_preview_thumbnail='avia-gallery-big-crop-thumb' thumb_size='portfolio' columns='5' imagelink='lightbox' lazyload='avia_lazyload']"); 
?>
```

Anybody know a way to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: You should use `WP_Query` instead of a raw SQL query for fetching post IDs. Also, you can't put a shortcode inside another shortcodes attribute, doesn't matter what PHP you write, it won't parse correctly and neither shortcode will work, `[this will="[never work]" ]`. You also can't put double quotes inside double quotes without escaping/slashing them, your `single.php` code should generate a PHP syntax error. You need to grab the IDs and construct a string like this: `do_shortcode( '[av_gallery ids="'. $image_ids .'" style...` where `$image_ids` is the comma separate list of IDs

Comment: Ah ok, would you happen to know a way to get the ids tag in the shortcode filled?

Comment: You already know how to do that, it's what the code in your other question about this does https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/384852/single-post-gallery-using-shortcode, I'd keep in mind that if nobody answers your question you should edit it to make it easier to read and solve, if you repost the question you are likely to be flagged as a spammer and auto-banned by  the Stack Exchange automation. Based on your other question,  it's highly unlikely that this nested shortcode solution you've devised will solve the problem, you've assumed getting the IDs into the shortcode is the issue

Comment: Also, I left notes on the code in the other question and you didn't respond. I've closed this one as a duplicate